# UI is being updated before useEffect finish reading data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The application shows incidents related to vehicles (such as breakdowns etc.) and the narratives (such as any communications etc.) related to that incident.

I have a `useEffect` in there, it reads three different files stored locally (within the application, as application data). Once these files are being read, it populates three different arrays.

These three arrays contain data, that are interrelated. I want to wait on, until all these data are being read and then interconnect the data. And then display the data on a UI.

At the moment it reads the data from files successfully via the `useEffect`. But the UI is updated before the data is read and processed, so it does not show the data properly.

Is there a way in React.js that it can wait until all the fetches are being read and then update the UI?

I have included my component structure. The data are being read at the "ServiceContent View" component, green circled, and the read data is shown at three places, "BriefIncident View", "GoogleMapReact" and "DetailIncident View" components, red circled.

[image: components]

I have used context and below is the code

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const VisibleContext = createContext({
    isIncidentVisible: true,
    isFilterVisible: false,
    incidentData: [],
    vehicleData: [],
    narrativeData: [],
    toggleIncidentVisible: () => {},
    toggleFilterVisible: () => {},
    fetchIncidents: (incidentsLocation) => {},
    fetchVehicles: (vehicleLocation, serviceName) => {},
    fetchNarratives: (narrativeLocation) => {}
});

export const useVisibilityStatus = () => useContext(VisibleContext);

const VisibleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [isIncidentVisible, setIsIncidentVisible] = useState(true);

    const [isFilterVisible, setIsFilterVisible] = useState(false);

    const [incidentData, setIncidentData] = useState([]);

    const [vehicleData, setVehicleData] = useState([]);

    const [narrativeData, setNarrativeData] = useState([]);

    const toggleIncidentVisible = () => setIsIncidentVisible(isIncidentVisible => !isIncidentVisible);

    const toggleFilterVisible = () => { setIsFilterVisible(isFilterVisible => !isFilterVisible); };

    const fetchIncidents = (incidentsLocation) => { 

        fetch(incidentsLocation, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (data) => {

            let incidentlist        = [];
            
            for(var i=0; i<data.features.length; i++) {

                let incidentObj        = new Incident(data.features[i]);
                incidentlist.push(incidentObj);

            }

            setIncidentData(incidentData => incidentlist)
                
        })
        .catch( (error) => console.log(error) );
    
    };

    const fetchVehicles = (vehicleLocation, serviceName) => {

        fetch(vehicleLocation, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (data) => {

            let vehiclelist        = [];
            
            for(var i=0; i<data.features.length; i++) {

                let vehicle        = new Vehicle(data.features[i]);

                if(vehicle.service === serviceName)  {
                    vehiclelist.push(vehicle);
                }                

            }
            
            setVehicleData(vehicleData => vehiclelist)
                
        })
        .catch( (error) => console.log(error) );
        
    }

    const fetchNarratives = (narrativeLocation) => {

        fetch(narrativeLocation, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (data) => {

            let narrativelist        = [];
            
            for(var i=0; i<data.features.length; i++) {

                let narrative        = new Narrative(data.features[i]);
                narrativelist.push(narrative);               

            }
            
            setNarrativeData(narrativeData => narrativelist)
                
        })
        .catch( (error) => console.log(error) );
    }

    return (
        <VisibleContext.Provider value={{isIncidentVisible, toggleIncidentVisible, isFilterVisible, toggleFilterVisible, incidentData, fetchIncidents, vehicleData, fetchVehicles, narrativeData, fetchNarratives}}>
            {children}
        </VisibleContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default VisibleContextProvider;
```

Following is the ServiceContent View component code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {useVisibilityStatus} from '../customhooks/VisibleContextProvider';
import IncidentListView from "../common/IncidentListView";
import SideNavView from "../common/SideNavView";
import SimpleMap from '../googlemap/SimpleMap';
import FilterListView from "../common/FilterListView";
import DetailIncidentView from "../common/DetailIncidentView";


function ServiceContentView(props) {

    const { isIncidentVisible, isFilterVisible, incidentData, fetchIncidents, vehicleData, fetchVehicles, narrativeData, fetchNarratives } = useVisibilityStatus();

    //this function is correct and returns the correct data
    function getServiceFileLocation(serviceID) {

        let serviceData = {};
    
        switch(serviceID) {
            case "1":
                serviceData = SERVICE_TYPE_1_DATA;
                break;
            case "2":
                serviceData = SERVICE_TYPE_2_DATA;
                break;
            default:
                alert('service id empty');
        }
    
        return serviceData;
    }

    //get service specific data location
    var serviceSpecificLocation = getServiceFileLocation(props.viewid);

    //fetch data
    useEffect(() => {

        //fetch incident, vehicle and narrative data for the service - declared in the context provider
        fetchIncidents(serviceSpecificLocation.incidents);
        fetchVehicles(serviceSpecificLocation.vehicles, serviceSpecificLocation.name);
        fetchNarratives(serviceSpecificLocation.narratives);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        //if incident, vehicle and narrative data available
        if(incidentData && vehicleData && narrativeData) {

            //set vehicles for each incident
            incidentData.forEach(incident => {

                let incidentVehicles = vehicleData.filter(vehicle => vehicle.vehicleIncidentNumber === incident.incidentNumber);
                incident.setIncidentVehicle(incidentVehicles);                
                
            });

            incidentData.forEach(incident => {

                let incidentNarratives = narrativeData.filter(narrative => narrative.incidentNumber === incident.incidentNumber);
                incident.setIncidentNarratives(incidentNarratives);
                
            });

        }

    }, [incidentData, vehicleData, narrativeData]);


    return(

      <div>           
          
        <div>              
            <div>
                <SideNavView />
            </div>              
        </div>

        {isIncidentVisible && <IncidentListView viewid={props.viewid} />}

        {isFilterVisible && <FilterListView /> }          

        <SimpleMap />          

        <DetailIncidentView />

      </div>

    );
}

export default ServiceContentView;
```

Below is where I display all the read data in the UI, which is the DetailIncident View component

```
import { useVisibilityStatus } from "../customhooks/VisibleContextProvider";


function DetailIncidentView() {

    const {incidentData} = useVisibilityStatus();

    console.log(incidentData);

    return (

        incidentData.map( (incident) => (
            
            <div className="modal fade" id={"inc-" + incident.incidentNumber} tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" key={incident.incidentNumber}>
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h1 className="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">{incident.title}</h1>
                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <ul className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            {/* Summary tab */}
                            <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button className="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true"
                                    id={"summary-tab-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    data-bs-target={"#summary-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    aria-controls={"summary-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}>
                                        Summary
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            {/* Resources tab */}
                            <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button className="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"
                                    id={"resources-tab-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    data-bs-target={"#resources-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    aria-controls={"resources-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}>
                                        Resources
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            {/* Narrative tab */}
                            <li className="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button className="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"
                                    id={"narrative-tab-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    data-bs-target={"#narrative-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}  
                                    aria-controls={"narrative-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber}>
                                        Narrative
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="tab-content">
                            {/* Summary tab content */}
                            <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id={"summary-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="summary-tab" tabIndex="0">
                                
                                {/* incident data are shown in here. */}
                                
                                {/* the data are shown correctly in here */}     
                            
                            </div>
                            {/* Resources tab content */}
                            <div className="tab-pane fade" id={"resources-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="resources-tab" tabIndex="0">
                                {/* at the moment this kept empty */}
                            </div>
                            {/* Narrative tab content */}
                            <div className="tab-pane fade" id={"narrative-tab-pane-" + incident.incidentNumber} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="narrative-tab" tabIndex="0">
                                {/* narrative data are shown in here. this is an array */}
                                {/* the problem occurs here. it shows length as 0, eventhough it has data */}
                                {/*  my guess is, 0 is shown because UI is updated */}
                                {/* before the data is read and processed */}
                                {incident.incidentNarratives.length}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <span>{incident.subHeading}</span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        ))   

    );

}

export default DetailIncidentView;
```

To explain the relationship between incident, vehicle and narrative are, incident can have 1 or more vehicles and incident can have 1 or more narratives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback of `useEffect` runs after the JSX is rendered. This is by design. And to have a new internal render, a `setState` should be called, which is a thing you are not doing in your second `useEffect` in `ServiceContentView`.

One way to resolve your problem is to ensure all data are **fetched** and **processed** before the UI render. For that, you could transform your data fetching functions to `async` functions:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const VisibleContext = createContext({
  isIncidentVisible: true,
  isFilterVisible: false,
  incidentData: [],
  vehicleData: [],
  narrativeData: [],
  toggleIncidentVisible: () => {},
  toggleFilterVisible: () => {},
  fetchIncidents: (incidentsLocation) => {},
  fetchVehicles: (vehicleLocation, serviceName) => {},
  fetchNarratives: (narrativeLocation) => {},
});

export const useVisibilityStatus = () => useContext(VisibleContext);

const VisibleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isIncidentVisible, setIsIncidentVisible] = useState(true);
  const [isFilterVisible, setIsFilterVisible] = useState(false);
  const [incidentData, setIncidentData] = useState([]);
  const [vehicleData, setVehicleData] = useState([]);
  const [narrativeData, setNarrativeData] = useState([]);

  const toggleIncidentVisible = () =>
    setIsIncidentVisible((isIncidentVisible) => !isIncidentVisible);

  const toggleFilterVisible = () => {
    setIsFilterVisible((isFilterVisible) => !isFilterVisible);
  };

  const fetchIncidents = async (incidentsLocation) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(incidentsLocation, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      let incidentlist = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
        let incidentObj = new Incident(data.features[i]);
        incidentlist.push(incidentObj);
      }

      setIncidentData(incidentlist);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const fetchVehicles = async (vehicleLocation, serviceName) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(vehicleLocation, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      let vehiclelist = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
        let vehicle = new Vehicle(data.features[i]);

        if (vehicle.service === serviceName) {
          vehiclelist.push(vehicle);
        }
      }

      setVehicleData(vehiclelist);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const fetchNarratives = async (narrativeLocation) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(narrativeLocation, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      let narrativelist = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
        let narrative = new Narrative(data.features[i]);
        narrativelist.push(narrative);
      }

      setNarrativeData(narrativelist);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <VisibleContext.Provider
      value={{
        isIncidentVisible,
        toggleIncidentVisible,
        isFilterVisible,
        toggleFilterVisible,
        incidentData,
        fetchIncidents,
        vehicleData,
        fetchVehicles,
        narrativeData,
        fetchNarratives,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </VisibleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default VisibleContextProvider;
```

Then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all data at once. And while fetching and processing, use `loading` and `processing`, two internal states, to render some loading component, like so:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useVisibilityStatus } from "../customhooks/VisibleContextProvider";
import IncidentListView from "../common/IncidentListView";
import SideNavView from "../common/SideNavView";
import SimpleMap from "../googlemap/SimpleMap";
import FilterListView from "../common/FilterListView";
import DetailIncidentView from "../common/DetailIncidentView";

function ServiceContentView(props) {
  const {
    isIncidentVisible,
    isFilterVisible,
    incidentData,
    fetchIncidents,
    vehicleData,
    fetchVehicles,
    narrativeData,
    fetchNarratives,
  } = useVisibilityStatus();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(true);
  //this function is correct and returns the correct data
  function getServiceFileLocation(serviceID) {
    let serviceData = {};

    switch (serviceID) {
      case "1":
        serviceData = SERVICE_TYPE_1_DATA;
        break;
      case "2":
        serviceData = SERVICE_TYPE_2_DATA;
        break;
      default:
        alert("service id empty");
    }

    return serviceData;
  }

  //get service specific data location
  var serviceSpecificLocation = getServiceFileLocation(props.viewid);

  //fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    //fetch incident, vehicle and narrative data for the service - declared in the context provider
    Promise.all([
      fetchIncidents(serviceSpecificLocation.incidents),
      fetchVehicles(serviceSpecificLocation.vehicles, serviceSpecificLocation.name),
      fetchNarratives(serviceSpecificLocation.narratives),
    ]).then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //if incident, vehicle and narrative data available
    if (!loading) {
      //set vehicles for each incident
      incidentData.forEach((incident) => {
        let incidentVehicles = vehicleData.filter(
          (vehicle) => vehicle.vehicleIncidentNumber === incident.incidentNumber
        );
        incident.setIncidentVehicle(incidentVehicles);
      });

      incidentData.forEach((incident) => {
        let incidentNarratives = narrativeData.filter(
          (narrative) => narrative.incidentNumber === incident.incidentNumber
        );
        incident.setIncidentNarratives(incidentNarratives);
      });
      setProcessing(false);
    }
  }, [loading]);

  if (loading || processing) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SideNavView />
      {isIncidentVisible && <IncidentListView viewid={props.viewid} />}
      {isFilterVisible && <FilterListView />}
      <SimpleMap />
      <DetailIncidentView />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ServiceContentView;
```

Comment: I have changed my code according to your answer and it worked ! Thanks so much for this. I knew I had to use async function, but could not figure it out on how to use it.